# Proving that if $| G : N |<\infty$ then $|H: H\cap N| <\infty$, where $N$ is normal to $G$ and $H$ is subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Prove that if $|G : N |<\infty$ then $|H: H\cap N| <\infty$, where $N$ is normal to $G$ and $H$ is subgroup of $G$

So far I have proven that  $H\cap N$ is a subgroup of $H, HN=\{ hn, h\in H,n\in N\} \vartriangleleft H$ in order to use that $|HN|=|H||N|/|H\cap N$|$  and I really don't know how to move on from here.

Some thoughts of mine are of using Lagrange's theorem in its general form:

If $G$ group with $K<H<G$ then $| G : K| = | G : H || H : K|$.

Comment: What do you mean by, say, $(G:N)$? Do you mean a semidirect product?

Comment: I guess they mean the quotient group, but let's wait for their reply, @Shaun.

Comment: i am sorry for the missunderstanding but it wouldnt let me put tex symbols on the title for some reason . I meant that the inidcator of N to G is finite

Comment: i am not sure whether it is called indicator or not since i am not studying maths in english

Comment: Ok, but then you should amend the title (beyond latex issues whatsoever). It is named "the index of (say) $N$ in $G$", and it is the number of the cosets of $N$ (in $G$).

Comment: oh thanks let me change it real quick

Comment: You could also show the correspondence $$h(H\cap N) \mapsto hN$$ is a well defined injection. Once you're able to do this the finite cardinality of $H/H\cap N$ is immediate.

Comment: great ! thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: G subgroups lattice]

Since $[G : N]$ is finite, we have $[G: N]=[G:HN]\cdot[HN  : N]$. In particular $[G:HN]$, and $[HN  : N]$ are finite.

Now, $N$ is normal in $G$, thus we have $N$ is normal in $HN$, $H\cap{N}$ is normal in $H$, and $\frac{HN}{N}\cong\frac{H}{H\cap{N}}$ from second isomorphism theorem. Then $[HN:N]=[H:H\cap N]$, and finally
$$[G: N]=[G:HN]\cdot[HN  : N]=[G:HN]\cdot[H:H\cap N]<\infty$$

In particular, $[H:H\cap N]$ is finite.

Comment: thank you very much!!